# Arraylist auto complete in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, arraylist, autocomplete

Im using eclipse and recently my auto complete for arraylist changed for some reason.

after typing: `ArrayList <String> myArrayList = new`, it usually auto completes the line to: `ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();`, but now when I do it, it auto completes to: `ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList()`;(Without the `<>`).
Does anyone know how to fix it? is it something in eclipse I need to change? or something in the jdk/something like that?
Thanks.

Edit - for some reason it doesn't display the full code, I did define the type of the arraylist to String, so that is not the problem.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg39a.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhb2.png)

Comment: Do you invoke ctrl + space after typing new ? If so, can you attach the screenshot on which item selection it brings the auto complete?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QFvHj here are 2 screenshots of the auto complete.

Comment: The link is not accessible. Can you please attach the image to the question?

Comment: I added it to the main question.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue. Is that issue reproduced to you always? Have you checked with the latest eclipse version. If that issue is reproducing in the latest version of eclipse also, please raise a bug in bugzilla (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) with the details (eclipse version, platform, build) after checking if such bug is not posted already.

Comment: I've done that, but just wondering, I also noticed now that it does the same when trying to use LinkedList for example...it still doesn't add the <> where it should. Any ideas?

Comment: It actually seems to be an issue with "Java Editor Content Proposal" (in eclipse terms) that might be common for all Generic types such as ArrayList, LinkedList. Please share the bug link so that I can also follow its status. Thanks.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531272 That is the link to the bug I applied, let me know if you are able to use the link. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the link works. Thanks

Comment: So I reinstalled my jdk, and that fixed my problem...so I guess that wat the problem..

Comment: The clue is the jdk version. In which version was the issue happening? What is the new jdk version you installed? The same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList<>` (<> is called Diamond), is valid when the compiled can "infer" this type.

Consider this

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here this "diamond" is known to be String.

But when you do a raw `ArrayList`, the compiler will NOT TYPE CHECK, this can cause serious bugs and crashes in big applications. Generics are meant to reduce bugs.

See

- [The diamond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond)
- [Why use Generics?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: Im terribly sorry for that, but I realize now that because of the site functions, it removed the <String> line, so that is not the problem, I did define the arraylist type, so what else the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: You say that you did define the arraylist type? That means it is not the standard ArrayList ? If so, so you didn't define it as a generic type   `class ArrayList<T>: List<T> { ... }`

Comment: It is a standard ArrayList, thats the problem..is it a problem with my java files? or is it something with eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your ArrayList in your constructor (or as a class variable): 
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList()

When you need to add to this array list just use myArrayList.add()